# xampp server and java client/server application

Tags: java, apache, sockets, xampp, winsock

hiho,

i intend to develop just a litte network application, something like a chat. so i downloaded xampp for windows and installed it (also as service), mysql included. well, i started the apache (and mysql) as service and just wrote the short line in java:

```
 try {
     Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 21);
     System.out.println("connection established");
 } catch ( UnknownHostException e ) {
     System.out.println("Can't find host.");
 } catch ( IOException e ) {
     System.out.println("Error connecting to host. " + e.toString());
 }
```

but directly i got the answer:

```
Error connecting to host. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

the server is runnin'. the localhost is accessible on the browser.

did i forgot something? any ideas?

Comment: other ports don't work too (ports >1024)

Answer (score 0):

In your java code you're trying to connect to port 21 (ftp). Don't know what you want to do, but perhaps you should try port 80 (http).

Comment: port 80 doesn't work. so i think, i need to check the configurations of that xampp..

Answer (score 0):

Did you download and install the Tomcat add-on for XAMPP? It's not part of the default install.

After it's extracted into the XAMPP folder you have to run first **setup_xampp.bat** and then **tomcat_start.bat**.

Also, Tomcat in XAMPP will use the 8080 port by default.